# Checking the expiry dates of SSL certs

Tags: shell, openssl, ssl-certificate

I  wrote  a script  to find the  expiry  dates  of  SSL  cert  in a  directory.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.0 *.pem *.key *.crt; do
    echo "## CERTIFICATE NAME -> $f ##"
     openssl x509 -noout -in $f   -issuer -subject -dates  
    echo ""
done
```

Are  there any improvements  on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't consider .key files - private keys don't have any expiry dates. Also, depending on your convention, .crt files might be PKCS12 files, in which case you would have to unpack them first.

Not sure why .0 files show up - if they are symlinks, you really should be looking only at the files pointed to. If so, the criterion for selecting files really should be to look at all links, not all .0 files (since there may also be .1 files).

Answer (score 2):

**Please check cmd to get Expected ans :**

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in abc.cer | grep Not`

```
Output :
        Not Before: Aug 30 10:14:54 2018 GMT
        Not After : Aug 29 10:14:54 2021 GMT
```

**Description :**   Use your `.cer` or `crt` certificate name